# Checking if directory exists always returns false

Tags: bash, unix

I'm quite new to the unix environment so i must be overlooking something basic... The following should generate a directory, only if it doesn't exist. I use it as a routine to generate multiple directories.

No matter how many times I pass the same arguments to the script, it always ends up creating the folder. I want to prevent the script from overwriting an existing folder. I've tried all sorts of checks, also trying the opposite form using "!".

```
for seqCall in "$@"; do
    IFS='_' read -ra args <<< "$seqCall"
    ss=${args[0]}
    hq=${args[1]}
    ri=${args[2]}
    cd ~
    echo " *** creating folder for SS$ss, with HQ$hq, and runID $ri ***"
    # check if directory to be created already exists. if so, add message and skip
    if [[ -d "${Daten/Runs/SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}}" ]] ; then
        echo " ACHTUNG: Runordner SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri} existiert bereits. Überspringe Neuerstellung. "
    else
        cd Daten/Runs/SS${ss}
        cp -r ../MASTER/SSX_SCEN_rX SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}
        chmod -R 777 SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}
        echo " Folder created..."
        cd ~
    fi
done
```

Comment: Compare your paths, they aren't the same `"${Daten/Runs/SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}}"  != Daten/Runs/SS${ss}/SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}`, also echo `"${Daten/Runs/SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}}"`, you see that it isn't the thing you want

Comment: Do you know that ${Daten/Runs/SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}} is performing a change?  What is written above says, using the variable Daten replace the first appearance of the string Runs with whatever SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri} expands to.  Was this your intention?  Assuming not, you would need to remove ${} from the outside of the above string.

Comment: Try `if [ -d "Daten/Runs/SS${ss}_HQ${hq}_r${ri}" ]`

Comment: @Ferrybig thanks for your tip. you were right - the paths were not equal. and thanks to @Vinny too, removing the `${}` was also necessary. if one of you turns this into an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

As above, run it without the external ${}.
Also, running with it should incur in a `-bash: ${...}: bad substitution` message on screen.